# C++ cli access Form variables from class

Tags: c++, variables, command-line-interface

There is a form Form1 which contains int x; and a class MyClass with .h and .cpp files. How can I access the Form1 variable x from MyClass, without passing it using a method? I think something like Form1.x Maybe is it a bad style of programming?
I am just learning..

Answer (score 1):

Well it breaks encapsulation, you should really have public getters and setters for the data you want to expose, allowing access like you suggested allows the caller to corrupt, reassign etc.. basically do whatever they like. You should add a method `getX()` for want of a better name.

C++/CLI supports properties which may be what you are after see msdn article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379617%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#vs05cplus_topic10 and a codeproject post: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10352/C-CLI-Properties-Syntactic-sugar-for-accessor-meth